# Error when Installing Wine on Linux: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F

Tags: linux, wine

I was installing Wine on linux and up on following the guide instructions on this article, [install wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), I came across these errors :-

- W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial
  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
  public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
- E: The    repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial
  InRelease' is not signed.

I looked for solutions but I could not find one. I decided to create a post and my solution to this problem.
Find the solution in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy.

Add the required public key using the below command line:-

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 76F1A20FF987672F
```

Now you can run:-

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

And you are sorted